# Exponential integral with $x^2$ and $\cos x$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, exponentiation

The first part is just a Gaussian integral and the second is the modified Bessel function of the first kind for $n=0$, but I couldn't find any information and what to do with their summation. Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you!

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \exp\left(-\frac{(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2})^2}{c_2}+ c_1 \cos\left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right) \,\, d\theta$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can't evaluate it which suggests it most probably doesn't have an analytical form. So you'll need to evaluate it numerically.

Comment: Thanks! I tried Wolfram as well (not Pro though) and got the same response. It has a pretty smooth shape, so a Riemann sum or other numerical methods should work pretty well. Ideally I wanted an analytical form as there is another integral outside of it that makes c1 go from 0 to infinity.